# Android FlexBox distinguishing when display is filled problem

Tags: android, view, flexbox

I'm using FlexBox in android (https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). The situation is: I push a button to add a view from a code. All views are added in one row and if there isn't enough space, they continue to be added on another row. The goal is to distinguish when switching to another line is performed or in other words, to understand if there isn't enough display space to continue drawing another element in the current row. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You can simply create a `FlexboxLayout` in XML and add views to it from code.
Check this example: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/demo-playground/src/main/res/layout/fragment_flexboxlayout.xml#L16

Comment: The goal is to change the properties of views on even rows. So I can't simply add in XML, it's not my way.